# RecyclerView efecto deslizamiento de los elementos de la lista

Tags: android

No se por donde empezar y me gustaría saber como hacer en cada elemento de un recyclerView que pueda deslizar hacia la izquierda (solo el elemento seleccionado) para por ejemplo poder eliminarlo o que salga un menu con iconos para poder ejecutar algo de ese elemento.

No se si me he explicado con claridad.